# Oozie-client is not getting installed on newly added node through ambari

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am trying to add one host to the cluster set up in Ambari, but Oozie is not getting installed properly. Here is the error in the log file:

```
Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install oozie' returned 1. Error: Package: oozie-4.0.0.2.1.2.1-471.el6.noarch (HDP-2.1)
           Requires: oozie-client = 4.0.0.2.1.2.1
       Installed: oozie-client-4.0.0.2.1.5.0-695.el6.noarch (@HDP-2.1)
           oozie-client = 4.0.0.2.1.5.0-695.el6
       Available: oozie-client-4.0.0.2.1.2.1-471.el6.noarch (HDP-2.1)
           oozie-client = 4.0.0.2.1.2.1-471.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: What have you looked into or tried?

Comment: i tried it. but now it's working i uninstalled the oozie and then tried to add host in ambari. now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installed oozie-client version is wrong.

Uninstall the actual one and install the oozie client version: 4.0.0.2.1.2.1

you can download it from here:

http://archive.apache.org/dist/oozie/4.0.0/